# IIS 10 - How to show DNS-alias / port 80 in WSDL-url for a WCF-service behind load balancer

Tags: windows, iis, wcf

Our IIS setup has a IIS Application Request server in front of three types of IIS servers (ruleengine, Microfocus Cobol on IIS and "the rest of the applications". All the basic setup of each server is done by a common script (Configure IIS and more). The DNS-aliases is "served" by the IIS ARR (port 80), and then it redirects the request to the server hosting the application with another port number.

When accessing http://myapp.test.mycorp.com/TheApp/theService.svc on the default page it shows

```
svcutil.exe http://myapp.test.mycorp.com/TheApp/theService.svc?wsdl
```

which is very fine, but on the two other servers - with the same basic setup - it will show

```
svcutil.exe http://theservername:theportnumber/TheApp/theService.svc?wsdl
```

Both sites are only bound to the port number, not the DNS-alias as well (did try that, but then it will show DNS-alias:portnumber and also prevent testing on the server using localhost and also using the severname)

What other settings / configurations on IIS can be different that would explain why the url is shown different on the different servers?

### Update

And now - noticed that for the .svc?wsdl is shows DNS alias and no ports. Nothing done for fixing the issue. Hoping that it has solved all problems, but checking .asmx?wsdl, it uses DNS-alias, but adds the port number. So then checking yet another service, a second .svc - all three on the same server. The last service shows the server name and port number (not the DNS-alias).

So now, it does not seem to be related to server configuration, but the services itself.

Comment: "No bindings for the site on neither of the servers", what bindings are you talking about? IIS sites cannot live without site bindings. "hen it redirects the request to the server hosting the application with another port number", edit your question to include the rules please.

Comment: I did update the text about the bindings now, hopefully it is clearer what I mean now